# Reload part of page, not whole page, once Ajax is successful. Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 for my project. I have a "newsfeed" of posts. Each post can be commented on. When a user comments on a post the page reloads and the new comment is shown in the comment box. How ever i do not want the whole page to reload. So, I'm able to submit the post using ajax. I submit the form and prevent the page from refreshing. However, now I don't know how to get the comment to appear on the post without manually refreshing the page?

Here is my **route** for posting comments:

```
Route::post('post/{id}/comment', ['as' => 'commentPost', 'uses' => 'CommentsController@postComment']);
```

The **controller** that posts this comment to the DB:

```
public function postComment()
 {
     extract(Input::only('user_id', 'resource_id', 'body'));
     $this->execute(new PostCommentCommand($user_id, $resource_id, $body));

     return Redirect::back();
 }
```

Im using a command bus that ultimately saves the comment to the DB like this:

```
public function leaveComment($user_id, $resource_id, $body)
{
    $comment = Comment::leavePostComment($resource_id, $body);

    User::findOrFail($user_id)->comments()->save($comment);

    return $comment;
}
```

**Comment model:**

```
public static function leavePostComment($resource_id, $body)
{
    return new static([
        'resource_id' => $resource_id,
        'body' => $body
    ]);
}
```

Here is the **view** that loads the comment box (contains all comments belonging to the post and a type box for posting new comments. I use JS to post the comment when user hits "enter/return" key):

```
<div class="comment-box-container">
<div class="comment-box">
@if ($type->comments)
    @foreach ($type->comments as $comment)

<div class="user-comment-box">

<div class="user-comment">
    <p class="comment">
    <!-- starts off with users name in blue followed by their comment-->
        <span class="tag-user"><a href="{{ route('profile', $comment->owner->id) }}">{{ $comment->owner->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ $comment->owner->last_name }}</a>&nbsp;</span>{{ $comment->body }}
    </p>
    <!-- Show when the user posted comments-->
    <div class="com-details">
    <div class="com-time-container">
        &nbsp;{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }} ·
    </div>
    </div>

  </div><!--user-comment end-->
</div><!--user-comment-box end-->
@endforeach
@endif

<!--type box-->
    <div class="type-comment">
        <div class="type-box">
        {{ Form::open(['data-remote', 'route' => ['commentPost', $id], 'class' => 'comments_create-form']) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}
            {{ Form::hidden($idType, $id) }}
            {{--{{ Form::hidden('user_id', $currentUser->id) }}--}}
            {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' =>'type-box d-light-solid-bg', 'placeholder' => 'Write a comment...', 'rows' => '1']) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
        </div><!--type-box end-->
    </div><!--type-comment-->


</div><!--comment-box end-->
```

and here is my **Javascript** for the ajax:

```
(function(){

$('form[data-remote]').on('submit', function(e){
    var form = $(this);
    var method = form.find('input[name="_method"]').val() || 'POST';
    var url = form.prop('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function() {

              ** I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE TO MAKE THE 
              COMMENT-BOX RELOAD AND DISPLAY THE NEWLY 
              POSTED COMMENT **

            }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
})();
```

Please note I'm very new to JavaScript and even newer to Ajax. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: In the success event of the ajax call, add a variable into the parameter section... something like success: function(data) .... and then you have the server response in that variable, from there you can just jQuery to update an element or how ever you wish to apply the changes to your page.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        // use a temp wrapper element to workaround weak jQuery HTML parser
        var tmp = $('<div>');
        tmp.html(data);
        // update the comment box with the new one
        $('.comment-box').html(tmp.find('.comment-box').html());
        // update the form (so it eventually shows validations errors)
        // don't forget to empty it via PHP if the submission was
        // successful
        $('.type-box').html(tmp.find('.type-box').html());
        tmp.destroy();
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm i still do not get anything. i have to manually refresh the page to show the new comment

Comment: Ops, the class selector was wrong in my sample code. Try now. It's just a proof of concept btw :)

Comment: yes i caught that. still not working for me. could it be because i have more than one comment box on the page? or does that even matter?

Comment: It may if they share the same class. Try to give each an unique id an try again and use that in your selectors. Also check your javascript console.

Comment: I can't see how I can make it work using ids because I will have thousands of posts, does that mean I will have to repeat this code thousands of times? I'm not sure how I can implement this. I'm basically trying to make a similar kind of comment system as facebook.

Comment: oh wow! i forgot to add `data` to `function()`. This works now1 thank you!

how ever once i submit a comment is breaks my javascript functionality for submiting the form with "enter/return" key. Do you know of a possible fix?

Comment: Right, sorry. You should try to use this code to register your onsubmit event:
`$('body').on('submit', 'form[data-remote]', function(e){` and a similar method should be used for every other event bindings related to dinamically replaced elements such as the form and the comment-box.